# Mapped domain and a blog on a dedicated IP

Tags: dns, ip, subdomain, domainservices

Is it possible to have www.mydomain.com mapped to a service, and a subdomain blog.mydomain.com on a dedicated IP for my blog or will the subdomain also be mapped?

Answer (score 0):

DNS handles the domain routing before any HTTP requests take place so yes, you can route "www.mydomain.com" and "blog.mydomain.com" separately.  You just have to make sure the "www" and "blog" entries in the DNS record for "mydomain" are set appropriately, the former to your service provider and the latter to your dedicated IP.